# What is the theory behing why is it harder to bend a block of wood on its thinner side when load is put onto it

Tags: bending

What is the theory behing why is it harder to bend a block of wood on its thinner side when load is put onto it as opposed to when the wood is on its thicker side. For example, if you had a 1x2x20cm length of wood with fixed supports at either end, when the 2cm is facing the ground it will bend more than when the 1cm face is facing the ground.

Comment: Consider the thickness resisting the load.

Comment: @SolarMike But is there any equation or something that shows this?

Comment: Google may be your friend, one result amongst thousands: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/290316083_Effect_of_loading_rate_and_thickness_on_the_tensile_properties_of_wood_strands

Answer (score 3):

The math used to quantify and represent this in calculations is called the  *second* moment of inertia.

Qualitatively, it is because the farther apart the faces under tension and compression, for the same degree of bending, the two faces must deform more. More deformation = more force required so the overall stiffness (*not* strength) is higher. Quite similar to pushing the short end of a lever with a spring tying down the long end.

It's why I-beams look the way they do, and why drywall is so much stiffer than either paper or plaster. Same goes for foam core carbon fiber laminates.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It is covered by the general beam theory.

The deflection equation for a simply supported beam with a concentrated load in the mid-span is $\delta = \frac{FL^3}{48EI}$. Since $L$ (length) and $E$ (Young's modulus) remain constant for both cases, we can drop the constants, and rearrange the equation to evaluate the force required for the beam to deflect in each case and compare the results.

$F = \delta*I$, for beam with rectangular cross-section,

$I = \dfrac{bd^3}{12}$, the second moment of area, a stiffness indicator. Note, for the purpose of comparison, the denominator can be dropped for simplicity.

For beam with 1cm width (b), and 2cm in depth (d),

$I_1 = bd^3 = 1*2^3 = 8$ cm^4

$F_1 = \delta*I = \delta*8 = 8\delta$,

Now let's flip the beam, b = 2", d = 1",

$I_2 = 2*1^3 = 2$ cm^4

$F_2 = \delta*2 = 2\delta$

The results indicate the beam with bxd = 1x2 is 4 times stiffer than the beam with bxd = 2x1, $I_1/I_2 = 8/2 = 4$, thus the narrower beam with greater depth requires 4 times of force to produce the same amount of deflection ($\delta$) as the wider but shallower beam, $F_1/F_2 = 8\delta/2\delta = 4$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Notice also that the strength of wood is *anisotropic*: the grain structure of the wood makes it stiffer in one orientation (called "vertical grain") and far more flexible in another (the "horizontal grain") direction, which are 90 degrees apart in the log.

The vikings knew about this and to make their ship hulls as flexible as possible, they cut oak planks with the tree ring direction running along the length of the board, which was ~tens of tree rings thick. You get "horizontal grain" boards like this by slicing them off the outermost layers of an oak log end-to-end, along its length.

If you want maximum stiffness instead, you split the log in half lengthwise and then cut boards off the flat surface of the split so the grain direction runs in the *thickness direction* ("vertical grain") of the board.

Comment: Thank you so much!